# how to get the view coordinate related to screen?

Tags: android

I have a `View` and it was giving me screen coordinate respect to its parent.
I have tried `getTop()` and `getLeft()` method of view, still it is not working for me.
I want a coordinate from main screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
 int[] location = new int[2];  // must be array of two integer.

 view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

 xAxis = location[0]; // 

 yAxis = location[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
Use `View.getLocationOnScreen()`  or `getLocationInWindow()` .

ex:

```
        int loc[] = { 0, 0 };
        View.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
        int x = loc[0]; // x position
        int y = loc[1]; // y position
```